# Recursively calculate length of string (error: list index out of range)

Tags: python, string, recursion, indexing, string-length

This is my code which should calculate the length of string recursively, bu it give error of list index out of range. Please correct Me!

```
s=list()
smallOutput=int()
def lengthh(s):
    if (s[0]=='\0'):
        return 0

    smallOutput=lengthh(s[1:])
    return 1 + smallOutput

strr="abc"
array=list(strr)
print lengthh(array)
```

Comment: `if not s:` should solve it ... python doesnt end strings with the null byte in general ...

Comment: Is there any way to add a null byte in it ?

Comment: By the way (if not s:) TOTALLY WORKED for me! Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that the string ends with a `null` byte.  Since you didn't explicitly add such a terminator to your string, there isn't one, and you ran off the end of the list.  Try

```
if len(s) == 0:
    return 0
```

Or, assuming that you're not allowed to use `len`, just

```
if s:
```

Or perhaps

```
try:
    dummy = s[0]
exception:
    return 0
```